# How to parse XML collection by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have this XML array (or collection), it can contains more than 2 items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<head>
  <word>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <answer>answer 1</answer>
    <question>Question 1</question>
  </word>
  <word>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <answer>answer 1</answer>
    <question>Question 2</question>
  </word>
</head>
```

I need to parse it in JavaScript collection with answer and collection by using jQuery. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is vague and broad, so all I can suggest is that you make an AJAX request to retrieve the XML and then use jQuery's standard selector methods to traverse it to get the data you require.

Comment: You can do this with inspiration, time, coding skills, and a little Internet search. Present a specific coding  problem you have, or take a book or a tutorial to learn basis of the language
read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Understood. Sorry for noob question, I'm new yet in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague but maybe this example can help you :

*(datas parsed using jquery and appended into a table)*

```js
var datas = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + '<head>' + '<word>' + '<ID>1</ID>' + '<answer>answer 1</answer>' + '<question>Question 1</question>' + '</word>' + '<word>' + '<ID>2</ID>' + '<answer>answer 1</answer>' + '<question>Question 2</question>' + '</word>' + '</head>';

questions = $(datas).find('question');
answers = $(datas).find('answer');


for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  $('#table').append("<tr><td> " + questions[i].innerText + " </td> <td> " + answers[i].innerText + " </td></tr>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Q</th>
    <th>A</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```